# What is the widget name of the Kde bar used in program like Kate? (image inside)

Tags: c++, reference, toolbar, kde-plasma

What is the object name of the Kde bar that provide buttons to hide/unhide widgets? I can't find on kde official API references. It's used in program like Kate, Kdevelop. Here the screenshot of the bar of Kate bottom: 
http://emilio.plugs.it/bar.png
[alt text http://emilio.plugs.it/bar.png](http://emilio.plugs.it/bar.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that a KMultiTabBar?